# m #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax I am all most new to SQL

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin

i am trying to run this CREATE Function code from (PhpMyAdimin)

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION  `CAP_FIRST`(input VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE charnum INT;
    declare SortedName varchar(255);

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 1;
    set charnum = 1;
    set SortedName = '';


    WHILE (i <= len) DO
        if charnum = 1 then
            set SortedName = concat(SortedName,upper(mid(input,i,1)));
            set charnum = charnum + 1;
        else
            if mid(input,i,1) = ' ' then
                set SortedName = concat(SortedName,' ');
                set charnum = 1;
            else
                set SortedName = concat(SortedName,mid(input,i,1));
                set charnum = charnum + 1;
            end if;

        end if;


        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN SortedName;
END
```

---

I always got this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need `DELIMITER` statements and you can use `elseif` and I would recommend replacing `mid()` with `substr()` or `substring()`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION  `CAP_FIRST`(input VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE charnum INT;
    declare SortedName varchar(255);

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 1;
    set charnum = 1;
    set SortedName = '';

    WHILE (i <= len) DO
        if charnum = 1 then
            set SortedName = concat(SortedName, upper(substr(input,i,1)));
            set charnum = charnum + 1;
        elseif mid(input,i,1) = ' ' then
            set SortedName = concat(SortedName,' ');
            set charnum = 1;
        else
            set SortedName = concat(SortedName, substr(input,i,1));
            set charnum = charnum + 1;
        end if;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN SortedName;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1               This is the error i get now

Comment: @MohamedTaher . . . Something strange is going on.  `DELIMITER` is definitely accepted MySQL syntax (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html).